# Laravel 5.3 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have just installed laravel 5.3 and created a new controller. I have defined the routes but i am not getting to this url. I have written this code in routes/web.php file. Here is my routes code :

Routes file:

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController@getIndex');
```

Controller file:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        dd("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you run a `php artisan route:list` and verify that it shows up in that list.

Comment: try Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');

Comment: @AngadDubey, yes its showing in cmd.

Comment: @TalhaMalik , still not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set routes like

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController@getIndex');
```

Routes will be created some thing like

```
App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@getIndex@store
App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@getIndex@index
App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@getIndex@create
and so on..
```

Change routes file as

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

And then rename controller method to

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
   public function Index()
   {
      dd("test");
   }
}
```

It should work fine.

Comment: Not working. Its laravel 5.3 and i am defining my routes in web.php

Comment: I just tried laravel 5.3 today and created simple application. And I just tried your routes and controller on my app. After chages I wrote it worked. can you share what URL are you hitting?

Comment: Sorry i can't share, working locally. i have created my controller via artisan command. Isn't it creating the issue?

Comment: the artisan make:controller command would not be creating the issue as it's focus is to just create the desired files within your application's directory and attribute the newly created file(s) to the autoload, per PSR standards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), 'users', 'UsersController@getIndex');
```

As, you will get access to only predefined methods through resource route.

Answer (score -1):

Route::resource('users','UsersController');